# Python: how to send html-code in a POST request

Tags: python, joomla, http-headers, urllib2, urllib

I try to send htm-code from python script to Joomla site.

```
description = "<h1>Header</h1><p>text</p>"   

values = {'description' : description.encode(self.encoding),
          'id = '       : 5,
         }
data = urlencode(values)
binData = data.encode(self.encoding)

headers = { 'User-Agent' : self.userAgent,
            'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'}

req = urllib2.Request(self.addr, binData, headers)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
rawreply = response.read()
```

At Joomla-server I got the same string but without html:

```
$desc       = JRequest::getVar('description', '', 'POST');
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRequest::getVar or JRequest::getString filter HTML code. But it can be turned off:

```
$desc = JRequest::getVar('description', '', 'POST', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use requests

```
pip install requests
```

then

```
import requests

description = "<h1>Header</h1><p>text</p>"   
values = dict(description='description',id=5)
response = requests.post(self.addr,data=values)

if response.ok:
    print response.json()
```

or if joomla didnt return json

```
print response.content
```

Comment: I'ts interesting. Almost all examples use urllib.
Thank you!